# How to return set<values> associated with a key?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a method where the parameter is a key to a HashMap and I want it to return the set of all the values associated with the key.
My hashmap takes object has keys and set of objects as values.

```
public set<Object> getValues( Object key) {
    }
```

object is just a class that i made.

So say that in my hashmap i have  key, object1, object2, object3.

I want it to return [object1, object2, object3]

EDIT: i have an instanced hashmap

```
private Map <Object, Set<Object>> hashmapexample;

public Class {
hashmapexample = new Hashmap <Object, Set<object>>;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Object object1 = new Object(1);
Object object2 = new Object(2);

hashmapexample.put(object1, new Treeset <object>());
hashmapexample.get(object1).add(object2);
```

I want to now add a method where it will return the set of all the values associated with object1 so...example) [object2] if i use object1 as a parameter.

Comment: Let's see your `HashMap`. Your question makes no sense without it. (It might also make no sense with it.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have already posted the answer in your own code!

```
hashmapexample.get(object1)
```

will return the set of objects associated with object1.

Comment: Or null, which needs to be replaced with the empty set